# Not sure why django South is trying to run reverse migration

Tags: mysql, django, django-south

When I run `python manage.py migrate api` it fails with "RuntimeError: Cannot reverse this migration."

The problem is, I'm not sure why it would even be trying to run a reverse migration? The file its failing on is 0025, which isn't mentioned in  the `south_migrationhistory` table in the MySQL database.

Any ideas why South would be trying to run a reverse migration with this command?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The full stack trace is:

```
Running migrations for api:
 - Migrating forwards to 0026_auto.
 > api:0025_auto__chg_field_article_curator_response_comment__chg_field_article_cu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module> execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/ubuntu/fake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/fake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/fake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/ubuntu/fake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/fake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 105, in handle ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/home/ubuntu/fake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 191, in migrate_app success = migrator.migrate_many(target, workplan, database)
  File "/home/ubuntu/fake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 221, in migrate_many result = migrator.__class__.migrate_many(migrator, target, migrations, database)
  File "/home/ubuntu/fake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 292, in migrate_many result = self.migrate(migration, database)
  File "/home/ubuntu/fake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 125, in migrate result = self.run(migration)
  File "/home/ubuntu/fake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 99, in run return self.run_migration(migration)
  File "/home/ubuntu/fake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 86, in run_migration print self.run_migration_error(migration)
  File "/home/ubuntu/fake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 286, in run_migration_error (self.format_backwards(migration), extra_info))
  File "/home/ubuntu/fake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 273, in format_backwards self.backwards(migration)()
  File "/home/ubuntu/fake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 57, in <lambda> return (lambda: direction(orm))
  File "/home/ubuntu/fakeapi/fakeapi/../fakeapi/api/migrations/0025_auto__chg_field_article_curator_response_comment__chg_field_article_cu.py", line 42, in backwards raise RuntimeError("Cannot reverse this migration. 'Image.article' and its values cannot be restored.")
RuntimeError: Cannot reverse this migration. 'Image.article' and its values cannot be restored.
```

Comment: Is that the only error you get, or is there more detail?  You might have hit an error that it then attempted to rollback - but you're only seeing the rollback error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the only relevant information, I've added the full stack trace just in case

Comment: I believe it is doing a check to verify that it is possible to reverse the migration. And since it is not possible throws the error.  If you are missing a migration, that would prevent reverse migrations.  Just a thought.

Comment: @mtnpaul, what do you mean by missing a migration?

Answer (score 4):

It has encountered a migration error, and tries to rollback it. You can clean up backwards migration temporarily and look what is the real error.

Comment: Thanks @ilvar, can you expound on how to clean up a backwards migration? I can't find any information online

Comment: Just comment out all code in `backwards` method and add a `pass` instead